# Convert type string to type object

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I need to show a users fullname in a console application, but I keep getting this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'UserCustomerNotes.User'

My code works when I only use `return user` but all that it shows in the app then is "UserCustomerNotes.User" and I need to show the fullname of the user. Can anyone please help. Here is my code:

```
public static User FindUser(User[] users, int noteid)
{
    foreach (User user in users)                
        if (user.ID == noteid) return user.FullName;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
public static User FindUser(User[] users, int noteid)
{       
    foreach (User user in users)                
        if (user.ID == noteid) return user.FullName;
    return null;
}
```

Is expecting to return a `string` object (the `user.FullName` value) when it succeeds in finding one, whereas the return type you've declared for your method is `User`. What you should do is this (where you're currently calling `FindUser`:

```
var ArrayOfUsersToSearch = GetAnArrayOfUserFromSomewhere();
var noteId = 3; // Or whatever value you want to use
var myUserToFind = FindUser(ArrayOfUsersToSearch, noteId);

Console.WriteLine("The users full name is: {0}", 
        myUserToFind != null ? myUserToFind.FullName : "Not Found");
```

And change the code in your `FindUser` method to be:

```
public static User FindUser(User[] users, int noteid)
{       
    foreach (User user in users)                
        if (user.ID == noteid) return user;
    return null;
}
```

The reason you see "UserCustomerNotes.User" output when you return `user` from your method is this:

```
Console.WriteLine(FindUser(users, noteId));

// instead of

Console.WriteLine(FinderUser(users, noteId).FullName);
```

Because the return type is `UserCustomerNotes.User` and it doesn't have an override of "ToString" to specify anything different, the default value that is given when Console.WriteLine asks your `User` object for its textual equivalent is its name. This explains why you see the "odd" output from your code currently.

> **Note**: I've put `Console.WriteLine("The users full name is: {0}", myUserToFind != null ? myUserToFind.FullName : "Not Found");` as your code can return null if it fails to find a user and you'd want to special-case the output you provide in that circumstance.

It's also worth mentioning, but unrelated to the question itself, that the format:

```
foreach(var x in y)
    do something;
```

Can be more prone to "breaking" if changes are made further down the line than if you explicitly call out the `{` and `}` around each statement block:

```
foreach (User user in users)                
{
    if (user.ID == noteid) 
    {
        return user.FullName;
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Impressed with the quality of this answer! +1

Comment: @AlfredBr, thanks =) It's quite long winded but I wanted to try and hit every point in the OPs question (including the Console.WriteLine output "oddness") and seem to have got a little carried away... ;=)

Answer (score 9):

Your method excpecting a return value of typeUser, if you want it to return name - change it to:

```
public static **string** FindUser(User[] users, int noteid)
```

or, alternatively:

```
if (user.ID == noteid) return user;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your function is of type `User`. Try changing it to `string`.

```
public static string FindUser(User[] users, int noteid)
{       
    foreach (User user in users)                
        if (user.ID == noteid) return user.FullName;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage (yes, nitpicking slightly! =) from an API point of view of having a method named `FindUser` that returns a users `FullName`, rather than `User`... If the OP was going to do this it would make more sense to rename the method `FindUsersFullName`

Answer (score 0):

You may define a `ToString` method inside your `User` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return FullName;
}
```

Then you can just

```
Console.WriteLine("User name {0}", user);
```